# Python Selenium time out explicitly

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My script does not come out to execute the next line after clicking below link.

```
monkey_click_by_id(driver, "fwupdatelink")
```

Is there any way to come out after clicking it explicitly without fail?

Comment: You can try setting implicitly wait to X seconds on the driver, if you're asking what I think you are.  It is not entirely clear what you are asking/trying to do.  Please try to provide an example and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be that the webdriver moves on too quickly before your scripts gets a chance to get the information it needs. my suggestions is to make it wait until the element is loaded by visibility which would  be the same as an actual user seeing the link show up in their browser. just to be safe.

try adding this code before your script. it waits for the element with ID "fwupdatelink" to be visible or otherwise just 10 second which ever is shorter.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"fwupdatelink")))
```

You could also use a try/except statement, just in case your driver gives you a timeout error.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.